# Is it ever possible to tell the purpose-driven purpose (in general sense) of a respected distressed disabled person?

Tags: meaning, purpose, life

I believe when a person is born God chooses him or her to carry out an action on this planet. And until that action is carried out they can never retreat from this world.

Paralyzed people fully from head to toe who are like so from birth and those people in life who developed some intense illnesses that they never quite got over with and can't rebuild their lives or help their family, what was that purpose-driven life for them?

I am asking this because I volunteer at an organization where broken people and people in wheelchairs come for help. I talk to them. I hear their distressing everyday life story. I want to know what was that God's chosen action that they have to carry out on this planet when they are so vulnerable themselves and are suffering so much?

I also heard on tv that a pastor saying every person's life has a grand design. So this question.

Comment: Thank you for this question. It's an interesting one, worthy of discussion. However it's not one for which there is going to be a single correct answer, but different people will have different opinions, and so it's going to be a poor fit for this site (where we really only do questions that can have a 'correct' answer). Don't let this discourage you from asking other questions here.

Comment: From the Catholic perspective: read books about saints and the meaning of suffering. If people knew about the meaning of suffering they would rejoice. In every cross we can unite with Christ's suffering and intercede the salvation of others. It's sad that many who suffer don't know about it or don't want to accept it. It goes into such waste.

Comment: @DJClayworth could this question be answered from the perspective of people who really like "A Purpose Driven Life" and its derivatives?

Comment: I'm afraid there's too much opinion in this question. I think you'll need to scope the question to a specific denomination or theological framework. For a start, I'm aware of a recently widely read pop culture book called "purpose-driven life". Could this be what you are referring to? Though not a theological work, per se, it is certainly a *Christian work* with deep theological underpinnings.

Comment: And at the risk of answering in comments, I have three thoughts for you to consider: 1) God's told us His ways are not our ways, thus understanding His ways comes with great difficulty. It is a test of our faith to believe in his goodness. 2) Any purpose God has put upon any soul will surely be carried out. God is Almighty and does not test us beyond what we are capable. 3) A God-given purpose need not be your own actions, and can be actions done to you. The Romans 9 clay pots metaphor teaches this. Indeed, even your misery alone can bring God glory and be the greatest purpose one has.

Comment: Thanks. If I ever have a chance, I will look into the book. Again thanks. But I was more interested in the perspective of Christianity. What does it say about people suffering from illnesses? What is their purpose in life? And @wildmangrove answered that well enough.

Comment: +1 for @3961 point #3. The purpose for the disabled people you are helping is likely for stirring compassion and opening our eyes to the evil in the world, which then drives us running back to God for protection. So it's not for the disabled people action to do, who after they can live peacefully with their condition, their purpose may well be for receiving care while still being positive about life and God.  A suffering person's testimony about God can make a much bigger impact than a theologian.  I'm reminded of how even after Holocaust the Jews still believe they are the chosen people.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> [Isaiah 43:5-7] Fear not; for I am with thee: I will bring thy seed from the east, and gather thee from the west; I will say to the north, Give up; and to the south, Keep not back; bring my sons from far, and my daughters from the end of the earth; every one that is called by my name, **and whom I have created for my glory**; I have formed him; yea, I have made him.

The purpose of life is to live for the glory of God. So all things and people, that include man and women, healthy and sick, young and old are created to glorify God, there is no other purpose.

> [1 Corinthians 10:31] Whether therefore ye eat, or drink, or whatsoever ye do, do all to the glory of God.
>
> [1 Corinthians 6:20] For ye are bought with a price: therefore glorify God in your body, and in your spirit, which are God's.

Now we can ask, How we can glorify God?

> [Romans 3:10-18] as it is written, There is none righteous, no, not one; There is none that understandeth, There is none that seeketh after God; They have all turned aside, they are together become unprofitable; There is none that doeth good, no, not so much as one: Their throat is an open sepulchre; With their tongues they have used deceit: The poison of asps is under their lips: Whose mouth is full of cursing and bitterness: Their feet are swift to shed blood;Destruction and misery are in their ways;And the way of peace have they not known:There is no fear of God before their eyes.

**We can't**

The only way we can glorify God is through Jesus Christ

> [John 14:6] Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, and the truth, and the life: no one cometh unto the Father, but by me.

Now that we are in Christ, this is how

> [1 Peter 1:16] because it is written, Ye shall be holy; for I am holy.

Being Holy, that is

> [1 Thessalonians 5:14-22] And we exhort you, brethren, admonish the disorderly, encourage the fainthearted, support the weak, be longsuffering toward all. See that none render unto any one evil for evil; but alway follow after that which is good, one toward another, and toward all. Rejoice alway; pray without ceasing; in everything give thanks: for this is the will of God in Christ Jesus to you-ward. Quench not the Spirit; despise not prophesyings; prove all things; hold fast that which is good; abstain from every form of evil.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. In general the purpose of life may be to live for the glory of God, but most would say that everyone does that in a specific way, and the question is how the people described might do that.

Comment: I do not see how the people described could not comply with those established in 1 Thessalonians 5:14-22 or 1 Peter 1:16. Since the Bible is not a motivational book, but the story of the redemption of the human being from the fall with Adam to salvation through Jesus Christ and God's love for us. The Bible gives indications of how God wants us to live for Him. The gospel does not change for people with disabilities, it is the same for everyone.

Comment: One possible purpose is prayer. Except maybe for people who are permanently unconscious, just about everyone is capable of some kind of mental prayer.